# Extracting frames from a stream in GStreaner

Tags: c++, gstreamer

Good day all. As the title suggests, I am looking to get individual frames from an active stream in GStreamer. I have read through most of the manual, and haven't found anything to do this specifically. The basic processing pipeline would follow:

Source (File/URL) -> Decompress -> MyProcessing

I understand that the best way to do this is through pads, but out of a desire for clean code, I was hoping to use playbin as I will be reading from both files and web-based streams. If this isn't possible, I will start writing with individual file and URL sources.

My question is, is there a way to use playbin in order to direct the re-constructed frames, along with metadata from the packet/stream, to a separate class/function/method? This could be using a tool that I didn't realize was in GStreamer or from outside functionality.

Thanks for your help!

Using: GStreamer 1.4.5, Visual Studio 2012 (C++v11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `uridecodebin` and its sink pads. It's as versatile as `playbin` and can be pipelined further.

BTW take a look at `imagefreeze` element.